# Probability of collision of sums of vectors

Tags: pr.probability, linear-algebra, random-matrices

Let $S_1$ and $S_2$ be sets of vectors from $\mathbb{R}^d$ that are distinct and let $\sigma(\cdot)$ be a non-linearity, e.g., a componentwise sigmoid function.

Does there exist a random matrix $R \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times k}$, e.g., a gaussian matrix,  such that the probability of $ \sum_{s \in S_1}  \sigma(s R) = \sum_{t \in S_2} \sigma(t R)$ tends to 0 as $k$ tends to infinity

Comment: I think you mean:  Let $S_1$ and $S_2$ be distinct sets of vectors....Let $\sigma$ be a non-linear function.  Does there exist a set of matrices $R_k$ such that the probability...tends to 0 as $k$ tends to infinity?  If so, it would help to say it that way.

Comment: I think this probability will usually be $0$ if e.g. $R$ is a Gaussian matrix and  $\sigma(\cdot)$ is a smooth function with strictly positive partial derivatives.

Comment: @MattF There is only one matrix, not a set.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Could you please elaborate on your comment.